# Change the label and icon placement for a Flex Spark ButtonBar control

Tags: apache-flex, components, flex-spark, spark-skinning

Im trying to create a custom skin for ButtonBarButton. I need to create vertical layout of icon and label placement like in this exapmle for mx ButtonBar component: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/01/08/changing-the-label-placement-for-a-flex-buttonbar-control/

Unfortunately there is no "labelPlacement" property in spark components and i cant find a way to change the default BasicLayout layout for custom SparkButtonSkin either.

Found a solution where you set icon position with function 'setStyle'
(in spark skin initializer Handler)

```
protected function sparkbuttonskin_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        setStyle("iconPlacement", IconPlacement.TOP);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an `iconPlacement` property in Spark Button. But if you want to put Buttons inside of `ButtonBar` component you have to do something like this http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/07/28/displaying-icons-in-a-spark-buttonbar-control-in-flex-4/

Comment: Thanks! I found another solution where you can define icon placement with setStyle function in SparkSkinButton class: `code`setStyle("iconPlacement", IconPlacement.TOP);